# "--target list" meaning in qemu installation

Tags: linux, qemu, system-administration

I am new to qemu. I have the following question. I needed to emulate some new instructions using qemu. Basically I modify the target-i386 to something like target-i386-extended. Add tcg/i386-extended.Since qemu supports many architectures, normally i configure using the following command

./configure --target-list=i386-softmmu --enable-debug

make

make install

Are there any changes that needs to be done if we want to emulate new target? If so, what needs to be the command in the above case?

Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 19):

```
./configure --help
```

shows option for customized building and compiling.

Standard options:

```
  --help                   print this message

  --prefix=PREFIX          install in PREFIX [/usr/local]

  --interp-prefix=PREFIX   where to find shared libraries,
                           etc.use %M for cpu name [/usr/gnemul/qemu-%M]
```

`--target-list=LIST       set target list (default: build everything)`

by default it will build for all your targets like x86,x86_64,arm.powerpc etc

`./configure --target-list=i386-softmmu`

this will build only for x86 target i.e you ll get qemu-i386 binary only.

if you want for arm target only then use

`./configure --target-list=arm-softmmu` which will build and compile only for arm.

qemu-system-arm binaries you ll get which you can use for emulating ARM board